# Query WooCommerce orders grouped by several order statuses

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic

As I can see from WooCommerce documentation, `WC_Order_Query` allows **only one single order status** to be passed as query parameter. Has anyone find some workaround to allow querying several order statuses in the same query?

Let's say I want to query orders with "completed" AND "refunded" status.

How can this be done via standard `WC_Order_Query` class?

Example from doc:

```
// Get orders on hold.
$args = array(
    'status' => 'on-hold',
);

$orders = wc_get_orders( $args );
```

Link to [`wc_order_query()` and `WC_Order_Query`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/wc_get_orders-and-WC_Order_Query#wc_order_query-methods) WooCommerce documentation

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The documentation on [`wc_get_orders` and `WC_Order_Query`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/wc_get_orders-and-WC_Order_Query) is poor… Now regarding the order status in a `WC_Order_Query`, **you can pass an array of order statuses**:

```
// Display "completed" orders count
$statuses = ['completed'];
$orders = wc_get_orders( ['limit' => -1, 'status' => $statuses] );
echo '<p>' . sprintf( __('Count of "%s" orders: %s'), implode('", "', $statuses), count($orders) ) . '</p>';

// Display "refunded" orders count
$statuses = ['refunded'];
$orders = wc_get_orders( ['limit' => -1, 'status' => $statuses] );
echo '<p>' . sprintf( __('Count of "%s" orders: %s'), implode('", "', $statuses), count($orders) ) . '</p>';

// Display "completed" and "refunded"  orders count
$statuses = ['completed','refunded'];
$orders = wc_get_orders( ['limit' => -1, 'status' => $statuses] );
echo '<p>' . sprintf( __('Count of "%s" orders: %s'), implode('", "', $statuses), count($orders) ) . '</p>';
```

Tested and works.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of passing 'status' parameter, you can use 'post_status' parameter as an array like this:

```
// Get orders on hold and process
$args = array(
    'post_status' => array('wc-processing','on-hold')
);

$orders = wc_get_orders( $args );
```

Answer (score 0):

It took me a while to understand for wordpress + woocommerce but this works perfect :)

```
if (!function_exists('custom_filter_for_shop_order')) {

    function custom_filter_for_shop_order($query)
    {
        global $typenow;

        if (
            is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && in_array($typenow, wc_get_order_types('order-meta-boxes'), true)
            && isset($_GET['filter_status']) && is_array($_GET['filter_status'])
        ) {

            $query->set('post_status', $_GET['filter_status']);

            remove_filter('pre_get_posts', 'custom_filter_for_shop_order');
        }
    }
    add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'custom_filter_for_shop_order');
}
```